# Spring boot jpa query returns no data

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have the below repository which extends `JpaRepository`.

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
//    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM users u WHERE u.email = ?1", nativeQuery = true)    
User findByEmail(String email);
}
```

When I call the function from the below mapping no result is returned, no empty object, nothing.

```
@GetMapping(value = "email")
public User getByEmail(@RequestBody String email) {
    return userRepository.findByEmail(email);
}
```

Found similar issues but with no actual answers. I have also tried native queries, as you can see the commented `@Query` annotation. The mapping is in a simple controller which just has a post function and a get function for all the users.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit ---

User model

```
package com.example.demo.User;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity(name="Users")
@Table(name = "users", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(name = "user_email_unique", columnNames = "email")
})
public class User {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "users_sequence",
            sequenceName = "users_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "users_sequence"
    )
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false) // Column options for the id
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String name;
    private String lastName;
    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String email;
    private int age;
    private int weight;

    public User() {}

    public User(String name, String lastName, String email, int age, int weight) {
        this.name = name;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.age = age;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(int weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show your Entity :)

Comment: Can you please add `User` model to your question? Thanks!

Comment: Added user model

Comment: How does the executed SQL looks and does this return something if you execute it with an SQL tool?

Comment: Yes @SimonMartinelli, If I execute it with an email instead of `?1` in the psql console it will return a record.

Comment: How does your HTTP request look like? Are you passing the email as request parameter or request body?

Comment: you should have a look at the log that Hibernate produces. https://www.baeldung.com/sql-logging-spring-boot

Comment: Are you sure your `Users` table is populated? What about if you run a `userRepository.findAll()` method, do you get results? And usually GET requests put their parameters in request params not in request body (though you can do this also). Can you show us how is your GET request?

Comment: Moreover you can put a breakpoint in `return userRepository.findByEmail(email);` debug and check the `email` variable if it comes null or populated with the String you expect. If it comes null then check your GET request if it uses request params instead of request body

Comment: `getByEmail` is a GET HTTP method, why did you pass the parameter with `@RequestBody`? It should be `path-variable` or `request-param`. And another important thing is your POST method, Are you sure the POST method can properly populate the database?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer in the docs of spring boot, only POST/PUT requests have a request body.

@RequestBody annotation binds the content sent in (POST / PUT) request body with the annotated variable. Since there is no 'body' part in GET request, spring throws HttpMessageNotReadableException to indicate the same.

As a general rule, you can only use @RequestBody for the requests which can have 'body' content e.g. POST or PUT.

Comment: Please, mark your answer as accepted, others will be known that you found the solution.